# Creating custom Docker image

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to understand how to create a custom image.

I'm working on an application that is in node.js and uses catdoc to extract text from text files.

I did pull the office node.js image through dockerhub :

```
git pull node
```

And ran the image through the command:

```
docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(PWD):/my-app -w "/my-app" node npm start
```

My application opens up a child_process calling catdoc, but it's not working, obviously because it is a node.js image, so I tried:

```
docker exec <node_container_id> apt-get install catdoc
```

and this returns:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package catdoc
```

I 'm trying to understand ... this image does not have ubuntu , so I thought "I will download the ubuntu and put node.js with catdoc there" ... but, well ... does not work:

```
docker exec <ubuntu_container_id> apt-get node
```

Returns:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: "apt-get": executable file not found in $PATH
```

What i'm doing wrong? How could i fix? I already read several tutorials, but i'm not getting it...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Node image on Docker Hub is based on Jessie (Debian) according to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/ae9e2d4f04a0fa82261df86fd9556a76cefc020d/6.3/Dockerfile). Docker images are usually as compact as possible, which means that things like `apt` caches are flushed before creating the image.

Your `apt-get install catdoc` fails because the apt package list is empty. If you run `apt-get update` before, it should work:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti node bash

root@5ef87ec1e333:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease                                  
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [374 kB]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [142 kB]           
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2373 B]                            
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]   
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [17.6 kB]
Get:7 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9032 kB]
Fetched 9780 kB in 5s (1762 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done

root@5ef87ec1e333:/# apt-get install catdoc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  tk wish
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  catdoc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 650 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2504 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main catdoc amd64 0.94.4-1.1 [650 kB]
Fetched 650 kB in 0s (679 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package catdoc.
(Reading database ... 21090 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../catdoc_0.94.4-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking catdoc (0.94.4-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Setting up catdoc (0.94.4-1.1) ...

root@5ef87ec1e333:/# catdoc 
Usage:
 catdoc [-vu8btawxlV] [-m number] [-s charset] [-d charset] [ -f format] files
```

You might want to write your own Dockerfile to create an image containing Node, `catdoc` and whatever tools you might need, and base your containers on that image instead of the official one. For example, create a Dockerfile containing (see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get) for more information about the `rm` command):

```
FROM node

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install catdoc && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then build your image with `docker build -t="test:test" .` and create a container based on it:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti test:test bash
root@eb7f087a2cbd:/# catdoc 
Usage:
 catdoc [-vu8btawxlV] [-m number] [-s charset] [-d charset] [ -f format] files
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your real question is...

**Q:** "Can I install `catdoc` on a NodeJS Image? If yes, why am I seeing errors when I do so?"

Yes, you can customize the official NodeJS image from Dockerhub to include the `catdoc` executable. In fact you were pretty close. You were seeing those errors only because you were missing the `apt-get update` step.

However instead of installing it on the container, you might want to do it on the image level? This is so that you don't have to be reinstalling `catdoc` whenever you spin that nodeJS container.

To do so, you can modify the downloaded NodeJS Dockerfile by adding the following 2 line.

```
# Installs catdoc executable onto the NodeJS ubuntu image
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install catdoc
```

Then as usual build the image. 
Example: `docker build -t nodewithcatdoc:test .`.

And start a container form the built image by doing the `docker run` command you got up and you should have a customized NodeJS + CatDoc container ready to go.